# Technique identification in a wrestling match

Tags: sparring, wrestling, weight

Please refer to the following [video](https://www.facebook.com/wayoftheshokunin/videos/1073011469446139/): as can be seen, the smaller man wins. 
What technique does he use? Where can I find more information about it? Generally, are there any additional techniques/ drills that smaller person can use against stronger/bigger opponent?

Comment: Can you explain how/why this question isn't a duplicate of your previous question [*What are the best techniques to fight with a heavier and stronger rival*](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/6003/70)?

Comment: Thanks @slugster, Here is a proven technique shown in the video. I'm interested specifically in the technique/ drills in the video. This question is specific.

Comment: This is Olympic wrestling.  I can't tell if it is Greco-Roman or Freestyle rules.  Probably best edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks @HuwEvans, I edited the question. I am interested in the specific techniques/ drills to be used for different sizes. I'm looking for the names and information of the drills.

Comment: I don't think the different sizes come into this as much as you think.  Just learn this style if you want to learn the techniques you see here.  It doesn't look especially self defence oriented (which I gather is what you are looking for in a style) but if you think it looks cool go for it.

Comment: Thanks @mattm, I'm looking for each shown technique that can help overcome the size and strength of the rival. (Maybe there is a source of drills I can look at). The pin at the end is a good start.

Comment: @HuwEvans If it were Greco, then the single-leg would be illegal. I'm also not sure what you mean by "Olympic" wrestling?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this sport Dave Liepmann.  However I thought that Avi would get better answers if he said it was wrestling.  I just said 'Olympic' distinguish it from WWE performance stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On youtube, this is titled [Jouko Salomäki vs. Hans Fell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7V1eUfccJo). In this match, you should notice that there is a huge skill disparity between the smaller man and the bigger man. The bigger man is uncomfortable and never actually produces an attack.

There are no magic techniques that will make small people win against big people. As I pointed out in my answer to your other question, you need to train techniques well to get them to work against bigger opponents. In any  martial art, you should be training with the mindset that your opponents are bigger and stronger. If you understand how to make techniques work on bigger and stronger opponents, it is straightforward to apply them to equal-sized or smaller opponents.

Here is the brief analysis of the wrestling techniques in the video:

1. ~18 sec single leg takedown. This is one of the first attacks you learn in wrestling. There are many variations.
2. ~30 sec [gut wrench](https://www.kolat.com/mid-level-gutwrench)
3. ~56 sec To me this looks like a [fireman's carry](https://www.kolat.com/firemans-carry-series) attempt.
4. ~60 sec [front headlock roll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QbgtFZoaE8)

What are the best techniques to use against opponents who are bigger and stronger? The techniques you are good at.